# Unloading R package and freeing memory

Tags: r

I have a Shiny application that sometimes needs some heavy-weight libraries (or, perhaps, some libraries with heavy-weight dependencies). I run several instances of this Shiny application on the same server, and the RAM used by each process is starting to get uncomfortably large.

I would like to load the heavy package on demand, only when the feature is required, and then remove it, freeing their memory.
Is there a good way to do this?

I tried using `detach` like this, but there is no change in memory usage:

```r
Packrat mode on. Using library in directory:
- "~/src/proj/ems/ems/packrat/lib"
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) limit (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 309196 16.6     654011   35         NA   654011   35
Vcells 622274  4.8    8388608   64      16384  1957831   15
> library(tmap)
> gc()
          used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) limit (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 2959222 158.1    5312251 283.8         NA  4946520 264.2
Vcells 4595134  35.1   10146329  77.5      16384  8388608  64.0
> detach("package:tmap", unload=TRUE, force=TRUE)
> gc()
          used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) limit (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 2960717 158.2    5312251 283.8         NA  4946520 264.2
Vcells 4598885  35.1   10146329  77.5      16384  8388608  64.0
```

In this case it actually makes sense, because `tmap` itself is apparently small, but it uses, for instance, `raster` which is quite big.
But even if I do the same sequence of commands with `raster` nothing changes.

Any suggestions?